# Getting out of debug mode in R Studio

Tags: r, rstudio

I was making an assignment which asked to see what happens if you execute

```
debug(ls)
ls
```

At that moment everything was fine, and it showed the function itself. But now that the assignment is over, I can't use ls again.

Debug mode is off, I've tried

```
undebug(ls)
```

and this didn't work either.

Is there a way to use back my function without any issue?

Comment: hit escape, enter Q, or hit enter at a blank line until you hit the end. Make sure you are using `ls()`

Comment: There should also be a red little square on which you can click to stop the debug mode.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Q got me out of debug mode